# BeautifulSoup extract text from different tags

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract text of article from webpage with the following HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
<div id='article_body'>
    <h2 class='article_subtitle'>subtitle_1</h2>
    <p class ='article_paragraph'>text_1</p2>
    <p class ='article_paragraph'>text_2</p2>
    <p class ='article_paragraph'>text_3</p2>
    <h2 class='article_subtitle'>subtitle_2</h2>
    <p class ='article_paragraph'>text_4</p2>
    <p class ='article_paragraph'>text_5</p2>
    <h4 class='videoTitle'>I DONT WANT THIS TEXT</h4>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I've tried:

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://......."
source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
article_text = ''
article = soup.find('div', {'id': 'article_body'}).find_all(text=True)
for element in article:
    article_text += '\n'+ ''.join(element)
print(article_text)
```

But then I'm getting also text from `<h4>`. Any advice how to avoid this?

Comment: `.find_all('p', text=True)`

Comment: But I also need subtitles from <h2>

Comment: @AlekSZ Then why can't you make that clear in the question?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought that was clear. But you are right - not clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
article_text = ''
article = soup.find('div', {'id': 'article_body'}).find_all()
for element in article:
    if '<h4' in str(element):
        continue
    # with html tag
    # article_text += '\n'+ ''.join(str(element))
    # inner text only
    article_text += '\n'+ ''.join(element.text)
print(article_text)
```

Comment: article_text += '\n'+ ''.join(element)TypeError: sequence item 1: expected str instance, Tag found

Comment: if not return string just replace `join(element)` with `join(element.text)`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything you want has a class that starts with `article`

```
articles = soup.find_all(class_ = lambda c: c and c.startswith('article'))
print('\n'.join(articles))
```